# CSS : Apply background to full width in a div with a fixed width

Tags: css, background

My page is divided in rows with limited width. (`<div class='row'>`)
I would like to apply a background (color) to each row, but I would like the back ground not to take into consideration the width limit of the div, is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can provide a fiddle, it may be easier to help you. Are you saying you would like the background to span fullscreen?

Comment: We'd need to know the structure of your HTML, at least, to be able to answer this (e.g., will the height of your divs be variable?). An example or screenshot of what you're trying to achieve wouldn't hurt, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Were you going for something like this? It'd be easier to answer your question if you provided a fiddle or atleast some code so we can help you with your problem.

I came to this solution:

```
<div class="row1">
    ...
</div>

<div class="row2">
    ...
</div>
```

```
.row1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.row2 {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

You can run it here: [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/akneg2pm/)

Comment: For me this is the best solution on this page.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible with a pseudo-element, no need for additional HTML.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
[class^=row] {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
[class^=row]:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  background: purple;
  z-index: -1;
}
.row1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.row2 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row1">...</div>
  <div class="row2">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great hack... I used to play with box-shadow, but this one has no limit, whatever the screen resolution!

Comment: It's better than the previous option which was **two** pseudo-elements (left & right) but that required huge sizes and negative margins **and** `overflow:hidden`. Can't say I invented this version...but I've never seen it offered anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better to place each row inside a .container-fluid div with a {min-width: 100%} and a custom class for the colour you need

```css
.container-fluid {
  min-width: 100%
}
.row {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid red">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Row Content 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid green">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Row Content 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid blue">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Row Content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```