# Bypassing max-width of parent: setting div width to 100% of window width

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I made a asp.net MVC site that is based on default design/view provided by Microsoft. So it looks exactly like [this site](https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/).

I made my app and now I want to change appearance a bit. And here is a problem: this default view template is made completly wrong.

What I want to do:
[image]

Why I can't:

There is _Layout.cshtml file that is the same on every page of my site (it's probably called "partial view"). Here is how it handles the main part of site:

```
<div class="container body-content">

    @RenderBody() <!-- HERE GOES THE MAIN PART OF SITE -->

</div>
```

In the view that is loaded by @RenderBody I want to create a div that is as wide as black navbar on top. I can't, because parent (div .container .body-content) has specified "max-width". So i can't make my div width to 100% of body.

- I can't delete max-width, because I want to keep the rest of view in
  place that it is now.
- I can't modify all views and add there some
   tags that have "max-width" and delete "max-width" from
  ".container". Or maybe I could, but it would be too much work.

**What do you advice me to do? Is there any easy way to make this div 100% width but without changing position of objects of view?**

Comment: What is the purpose of making that div 100% of the body width? Is it just to extend the background to the viewport edge?

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't know what the viewport edge is, but it the final effect should look like this: https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Then yes you can - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826488/css-apply-background-to-full-width-in-a-div-with-a-fixed-width/29826806#29826806

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try is split the content page.
The grey Contoso University would be its own div and you could change anything with keeping the second div with the original css you have intact.

Comment: You mean i should place it outside ".container" div? It would be hard to accomplish, "Contoso university" div is also rendered by @RenderBody() so I can't do it

Comment: from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property you can try t set a width above 100% but I would not recommend it except if you really cannot do otherwise

Answer (score 0):

basically instead of this HTML:

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Contoso University</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Welcome to Contoso University</h2>
            <p>
            Contoso University is a sample application that
            demonstrates how to use Entity Framework 6 in an
            ASP.NET MVC 5 web application.
            </p>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Build it from scratch</h2>
        <p>You can build the application by following the steps in the tutorial series on the ASP.NET site.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/">See the tutorial »</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Download it</h2>
        <p>You can download the completed project from the Microsoft Code Gallery.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Application-b01a9fe8">Download »</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

you may use:

```
<div class=" body-content">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Contoso University</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Welcome to Contoso University</h2>
            <p>
            Contoso University is a sample application that
            demonstrates how to use Entity Framework 6 in an
            ASP.NET MVC 5 web application.
            </p>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Build it from scratch</h2>
        <p>You can build the application by following the steps in the tutorial series on the ASP.NET site.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/">See the tutorial »</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Download it</h2>
        <p>You can download the completed project from the Microsoft Code Gallery.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Application-b01a9fe8">Download »</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just made two diferents `<div class="container body-content">` one with your grey header and one for your content and remove `container`class from the first one (that class sets `the max-width` of the `div`)

Or (as I have readed just now your comment in another answer) remove the class `container` and add it JUST to whatever dinamic div with the content inside you need to have a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit hacky, but it worked for me.  It's basically creating a pseudo-element that is the same height as the current gray bar, and setting it to a full-width gray bar.

add this to your CSS (you might also need to play with the height of the "jumbotron" bar to make it perfect):

```
.jumbotron:after{
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:240px;
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    background:#EEEEEE;
}
```

Comment: I want to create more than one div's of that type (with full width). Height should fit automatically to the height of text in this div. Your way works, but it's too "tricky" ;)

Comment: in that case, you'll probably need to set the container to 100% width, and then individually reset the widths of all the inner pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by container body-content
The example is below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just remove the class name

from :

```
div class="container body-content">

    @RenderBody() <!-- HERE GOES THE MAIN PART OF SITE -->
/div>
```

to :

```
<div>

    @RenderBody() <!-- HERE GOES THE MAIN PART OF SITE -->
/div>
```

It works